# In performing geometric operations on a graph of a function that is being transformed, must you scale before you shift?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

> The graph of $f(x) = \sqrt x$ is the original function. Through
>   transformation, $f(x)$ is changed to become $\sqrt{2x+1}$. Why can we
>   not do the following:
>
> 1. $f(x) = \sqrt x$ ==> Graph is straighforward
> 2. $g(x) = f(x+1) = \sqrt{x+1}$ ==> Graph is $\sqrt x$ shifted $1$ to the left
> 3. $k(x) = g(2x) = \sqrt{2x+1}$ ==> Graph is $\sqrt{x+1}$ compressed by factor of $2$.

But the proper graph of $\sqrt{2x+1}$ is a graph of $\sqrt x$ starting at point $(\frac{-1}{2}, 0)$. Why does my method not work? But if you scale first, then shift the function:

1. $f(x) = \sqrt x$
2. $g(x) = f(2x)$
3. $k(x) = g(x+\frac{1}{2})$

the proper graph is the result.

Comment: The graph wont shift by 1 . Consider √x=√2 then √x+1=√3  so we see the shift approx it is 1.73-1.41=0.32 also if you compress then the graph would be of √2x+2. So your method is giving wrong results. I hope i cleared your doubt.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to bring forward the factor two:

$$\sqrt{2x+1}=\sqrt{2\left(x+\frac12\right)}=g\left(x+\frac12\right)$$

where

$$g(x)=\sqrt{2x}.$$

$g(x)$ is easy to plot then so is it $g\left(x+\frac12\right).$

In the following figure the blue line is $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, the purple line is $g(x)=f(2x)$ and the green line is $g\left(x+\frac12\right)=f\left(2(x+\frac12)\right)=f(2x+1)=\sqrt{2x+1}.$

[image]